# nginx proxy pass rewrite rule when the first path parameter is not fixed

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Need help with below nginx proxy/rewrite rule -

Request: https://**domain1.com**/{cc}-{lc}/**news**/article 
--needs to proxy forwarded like below -- 
Target: https://**domain2.com**/{cc}-{lc}/**info**/article

Examples-

Request: https://domain1.com/us-en/news/welcome_2020 
--needs to proxy forwarded like below -- 
Target: https://*domain2.com*/us-en/*info*/welcome_2020

Request: https://domain1.com/fr-fr/news/welcome_2020 
--needs to proxy forwarded like below -- 
Target: https://*domain2.com*/fr-fr/*info*/welcome_2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
location ... { # your location
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/news(/.*) $1/info$2 break;
    ... # all the other proxy setup
    proxy_pass ...
}
```

Comment: the location part is not fixed and it would be like this - location  ~* "^/((\w+)-(\w{2})\/news\/?)$" -- is location with regex and rewrite rule allowed?

Comment: Yes, it is. However having that location your captured groups variables (`$1`, `$2`, ...) will be overwritten with this rewrite rule. You need to use named capturing groups like `location ~* "^/(?<path>(?<lngprefix>\w+)-(?<lngsuffix>\w{2})\/news\/?)$` and use them later like `$path` instead of `$1`, `$lngprefix` instead of `$2`, `$lngsuffix` instead of `$3` and so on.